# how to verify object using xpath if object is invisible in selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can I verify invisible objects which gets enabled only on incorrect data entry (label before textbox eg: login scenario) using xpath in selenium webdriver.

If all labels display with error message (e.g. username label and password label),I am able to verify and capture text (error messages).
xpath Username: .//*[@id='loginForm']/p[1]/p/label
xpath Password: .//*[@id='loginForm']/p[2]/p/label

But if I enter correct Username,Webdriver continue searching for that Xpath for username(.//*[@id='loginForm']/p[1]/p/label) and does not respond.

HTML are visible only if error appears:
label class="error" generated="true" for="userName" 
label class="error" generated="true" for="passwordField

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: asfaik if the element is only invisible WebDriver should find it, and you can get the get the status of it using isVisible();

Comment: Make sure by 'invisible' you're not meaning a element that is not present on the DOM and gets added after a js request.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I am using Java. so there is only 3 methods to verify isDisplayed,isEnabeled and isSelected

Comment: I think you are right..code is as below:                                   <div class="formtop x">
        <div class="fields x">
         <logic:messagesPresent name="org.apache.struts.action.ERROR" property="alreadyLoggedIn">
          <html:errors property="alreadyLoggedIn" />
         </logic:messagesPresent>
         <logic:messagesPresent name="org.apache.struts.action.ERROR" property="activationError">
          <html:errors property="activationError" /> how can verify errors using webdriver ?

Comment: What i would like to know is the generated HTML, that seems like source code.

Comment: Here is HTML: </div>
     <p class="x trans"><label>Email</label><input type="text" name="userName" maxlength="250" size="20" value="" id="userName"></p>
     <p class="x trans"><label>Password</label>
     
     <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="passwordField"><span><a class="fp" href="#">Forgotten Password?</a></span></p>
     <p class="x trans"><button type="submit">Login</button></p>
    </form>
   </div>

Comment: That's my point on the first comments. If the element is not generated on the HTML, WebDriver can't bind it to a WebElement.

Comment: Thanks! but how can I verify error messages now?

Comment: Hi I tried with error then it is showing as follow HTML:<p class="x trans"><p class="x"><label class="error" for="userName" generated="true">
      Please enter a valid Email Address. 
    </label></p><label></label>   which appears only on incorrect data entry

Comment: Can you be less specific in your xpath, i.e. try only to match the `label` which should find both "normal" and "error" labels and then read its contents? Oh, and by the way, if you post more code it might be better to edit your original question, adding more info there and then maybe just add a comment that you have updated your question to notify any listeners? (not sure if the latter is really necessary) Editing the question gives you more formatting options,and people reading the question do not have to wade through the comments.

Comment: Ya I have edited my original question. But as i told that i can read label content only if error appears otherwise Webdriver continue search for xpath ".//*[@id='loginForm']/p[1]/p/label" for username and dont respond.

Answer (score 0):

Use a WebDriverWait:

```
WebDriverWait waiting = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
waiting.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginForm']/p[1]/p/label")));
```

The above will create a web driver wait object that will wait for up to 15 second (checking the condition every 100ms) for the element to become invisible.  This will pass straight away if the element is already invisible when the line of code is triggered.

**Edit based upon comments below**

If you are just trying to find out if an element exists of not you can do:

```
List<WebElement> labelCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginForm']/p[1]/p/label"));
```

If the size is 0 the label isn't there, else it is there, so something like:

```
if(labelCount.size() == 0){
    //Get tab text
} else {
    //Enter second field data
}
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working ,as I mentioned before that it appears only when error message appears. Otherwise webdriver does not respond.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear what you are asking for, I was under the impression you wanted to verify that an element had become invisible.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I want to capture error message on Textbox's Tab out action if it appears ,not then it should enter second field's data.I am able to capture error messages if both labels are displaying error.If one doesn't show error message then it dont enter second field data,continuously search xpath for first error label.HTML is:                      label class="error" generated="true" for="userName" label .If I am not wrong ,to seeing HTMLs ,it enables only at the wrong data entry

Comment: if error message is not displaying then HTML also is not displaying for error label